# Framework for revision tracking of entities in MySQL (and php)?

Tags: php, mysql, database, versioning

I have to set up a CMS in MySQL and PHP to power a website that displays information.  the website won't experience much traffic.  For simplicity sake, let's say this website will display information about schools and students.

One of the requirements I'm deliberating over is version control of some entities in the database.  Here are some entities that I will definitely need:

- School - there are about 100 schools
- School_Pictures - each school has many pictures
- Student - there can be 100 000 students, with each student belonging to only one school

I know that when a content editor wants to edit the information about a school, he is likely to edit both the record in the school entity and all the pictures for the school.  So both the school information and the school pictures should be version controlled, and nothing should be sent live until the content editor explicitly publishes the relevant records in school and school_pictures.  However, student information and which school they go to should NOT be affected by the version control School and School_pictures.

I read somewhere else that in SQL Server 2008, they have things like CDC.  Is there an equivalent for MySQL?   Or is CDC-related technologies even applicable to my scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it exists for MySQL in such a cake eater friendly form, but you can [build the equivalent](http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/Transaction%20time%20validity%20in%20MySQL.pdf) of CDC relatively easily using triggers.

Note also that CDC is not designed to handle change approvals by humans, that would still be implemented in your application logic even with SQL Server 2008.